# Arduino ethernet shield doesn't send data - REST API

Tags: arduino, ethernet

I have a little problem with function GET function of HTTP. The program reads ID number, and after enter(new line), it should get data from REST API. Problem is that I have to press enter twice for data from API. Here is code

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Ethernet.h>

byte mac[] = { 0x90, 0x02, 0xBA, 0xEF, 0xCA, 0x33 };
char server[] = "xxx.xx"; 

EthernetClient client;
char tmp;
char buffer[30];
int bufferCounter = 0;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while (!Serial) {
    ; // wait for serial port to connect. Needed for native USB port only
  }



if (Ethernet.begin(mac) == 0) {
    Serial.println("Failed to configure Ethernet using DHCP");
  }
  delay(1000);
  Serial.println("Ready");

}

void getData(char* num ){
Serial.println("connecting...");
if (client.connect(server, 80)) {
    Serial.println("connected");
    client.print("GET /api/id/");
    client.print(num);
    client.println("/?format=json HTTP/1.1");
    client.println("Host: xxx.xx");
    client.println("Authorization: Token xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
    client.println("Connection: close");
    client.println();
  } else {
    // if you didn't get a connection to the server:
    Serial.println("connection failed");
  }

    while (client.available()) {
    char c = client.read();
    Serial.print(c);
  }

    if (!client.connected()) {
    Serial.println();
    Serial.println("disconnecting.");
    client.stop();
    }
}


void loop() {
    if (Serial.available() > 0) {
       tmp = Serial.read();
       if(tmp == '\n'){
        buffer[bufferCounter] = 0;
        bufferCounter = 0;
        Serial.println(buffer);
        getData(buffer);
       }
       else{
        buffer[bufferCounter] = tmp;
        bufferCounter++;
       }
  }

}
```

On the serial link I get this message. At first

```
Ready
```

when I write there 35 and press enter I get this

```
35
connecting...
connected
```

then I have to press enter again, and finally I get the correct data but with connection failed and I dont know why

```
connecting...
connection failed
HTTP/1.1 404 NOT FOUND
Date: Tue, 22 Nov 2016 16:18:18 GMT
Content-Type: application/json
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: close
Allow: GET, PUT, PATCH, DELETE, HEAD, OPTIONS
Vary: Accept, Cookie

18
{"detail":"not found."}
0


disconnecting.
```

Could someone help me, where is the problem? Thank you.

Comment: Maybe the response isn't returned immediately after you send the request?

Comment: Unfortunately not, I tried to wait for 5 minutes and nothing happened